# Program that simply slows down a network?

Tags: networking

This may seem like an odd question, but I have my reasons. I wanted to ask whether there is a specific program or shell that I can run to just make constant requests to a network which just eats bandwidth? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

[T50 network packet injector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/t50/)

Download the deb file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/t50/files/t50-5.4.1/) and install it. Then you can run:

```
sudo t50 --flood --turbo --protocol T50 <host>
```

You can try flooding the default gateway or the entire network (run `ip route list` to list them). Run something like:

```
sudo t50 --flood --turbo --protocol T50 192.168.0.1
sudo t50 --flood --turbo --protocol T50 192.168.0.0/24
```